# Imported function not working?

Tags: python, function, return, python-import

In one module I have a function such as :

```
def check_answer(num1, num2, ans, op):
    int(num1)
    int(num2)
    int(ans)
    if op == "-":
        return num1 - num2 == ans
    if op == "+":
        return num1 + num2 == ans
```

in a seperate module. I tested the function.

```
import myfunctions

myfunctions.check_answer(1,1,2,"+")
```

It usually returns a true/false value. But now that I've imported it. It returns nothing?

Comment: Please fix indentation

Comment: Did the import fail? (You should be getting some sort of error in that case.)

Comment: What do you think `int(num1)` is doing? did you mean to do: `num1 = int(num1)`. Further, did you mean to: `print(myfunctions.check_answer(1,1,2,"+"))` - you probably get the correct result only you never printed it to screen

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're getting an import error, it looks like it is returning a value, but you don't seem to be doing anything with it. Try printing it:

```
import myfunctions

print(myfunctions.check_answer(1, 1, 2, "+"))
```

The output should be `True`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this firstly:

```
import myfunctions
print(myfunctions)
```

If you don't see a Exception,it may prove that you imported successfully.Then,try to print your result like this:

```
print(myfunction.check_answer(1,1,2,"+"))
```